# jQuery how to wrap a table cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, wrapper

I'd to add a wrapper around a row with jquery. I've made several attempts but am not able to. I'm only able via have a html template and filling in but doing orig.html() I lose any input selections values that were there.

Original html:

```
    <table><tbody>
  <tr id="myitem1"><td>I need a coat1</td></tr>
  <tr id="myitem2"><td>I need a coat2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

===
I want to use jQuery to wrap the rows and add a button cell and get a result of:

```
 <table><tbody>
  <tr id="myitem1">
   <td>
    <table><tbody>
     <tr><td>I need a coat1</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </td>
   <td><input type="button" value="click1"></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr id="myitem2">
   <td>
    <table><tbody>
     <tr><td>I need a coat2</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </td>
   <td><input type="button" value="click1"></td>
  <tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: do you really need to have another table within a table cell?

Comment: yes the original myitem1 may have several td I want keep together in formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to take all the columns in each row, wrap them into a table inside a single column and then add a column to the row.

```
$('tr').each( function() {
   $(this).children().wrapAll('<td><table><tr></tr></table></td>');
   $(this).append('<td><input type="button" value="click1"></td>');
});
```

Comment: nice and clean maybe add the [id^='myitem'] check

Comment: Looked like it was applying to all rows to me.

Comment: cool thanks for the solution I hadn't used wrapAll before, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var flowbox_table = $('img.flowbox').wrap('<table />');
    var flowbox_tr = $(flowbox_table).wrap('<tr />');
    var flowbox_td = $(flowbox_tr).wrap('<td />');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `tr[id^='myitem']` to select it.

The selector *<tag>*[*<attr>*^='*<prefix>*'] selects all elements of the `tag` with attribute `attr` that starts with the `prefix`.

Here is the whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

function template(pStr, pAttrs) {
    return pStr.replace(/{\$([^}]*)\$}/g, function (a, pName) {
        return pAttrs[pName];
    });
}

const TDReplaceTemplate =
"   <td>"                                              + "\n" +
"    <table><tbody>"                                   + "\n" +
"     <tr>{$OrgTD$}</tr>"                              + "\n" +
"    </tbody></table>"                                 + "\n" +
"   </td>"                                             + "\n" +
"   <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"click1\"></td>" + "\n";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr[id^='myitem']").each(function(aTR) {
        const aOrgTD = $(this).html();
        const aNewTD = template(TDReplaceTemplate, { OrgTD: aOrgTD } );
        $(this).html(aNewTD);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table><tbody>
  <tr id="myitem1"><td>I need a coat1</td></tr>
  <tr id="myitem2"><td>I need a coat2</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I had done something like that, but the this.html() loses any form selection values so I couldn't use it.

Comment: ??? Would you elaborate more how do you loose it? You have a form outside wrapping all the table with other input component?

Comment: if user picked an item from a pull down select, that info would not be carried into the .html() output string